# Error importing images when deploying React application using VITE in Vercel

Tags: reactjs, vite, vercel

Error when performing depoloy in VERCEL

I'm trying to deploy an application in react using VITE in vercel but it's generating the following error:

[image]

In my local file, this import is being carried out normally and the entire application works.

Could you help me please?

I did the tests in the local repository and all image imports are working normally. It was deleted from github, tested on another account and still has a problem